# Three.js map 2D to 3D using orthogonal camera

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I have a three.js scene using an Orthographic Camera

```
this.camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(this.width / - 2, this.width / 2, this.height / 2, this.height / - 2, 1, 1000);
this.camera.position.z = this.width / 2;
this.scene.add(this.camera);
```

Then I have a cube (red) that I would like to position at some 2D coordinates (green). I am currently using this function to translate 2D coordinates into 3D coordinates.

```
from2Dto3D( position2d ) {
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3(),
        camera = this.camera,
        x = (position2d.x / this.width) * 2 - 1,
        y = (position2d.y / this.height) * 2 + 1;
    vector.set(x, y, 0.5);
    vector.unproject(this.camera);
    var direction = vector.sub(this.camera.position).normalize(),
        distance = - this.camera.position.z / direction.z,
        scaled = direction.multiplyScalar(distance),
        coords = this.camera.position.clone().add(scaled);
    return new THREE.Vector3(coords.x, coords.y, 0);
  }
```

...

```
let position3d = this.from2Dto3D(position2d);
```

...

```
this.cube.position.x = position3d.x; // updating only x position for the moment
```

> How can I position the cube exactly at the 2D position ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to show more code. How do we know the issue isn't with your mouse position calculation?

Here is code that should work regardless of camera orientation and as long as there are no css transforms applied to the canvas.

```
      canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
        const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
        // get a canvas content pixel position
        const {width, height} = renderer.domElement;
        const canvasX = (e.clientX - rect.left) * width / rect.width;
        const canvasY = (e.clientY - rect.top) * height / rect.height;

        const clipX = (canvasX / width)  *  2 - 1;
        const clipY = (canvasY / height) * -2 + 1;

        // get the object's clip space Z
        const clipPos = new THREE.Vector3();
        mesh.getWorldPosition(clipPos);
        clipPos.project(camera);

        const pos = new THREE.Vector3(clipX, clipY, clipPos.z);
        pos.unproject(camera);
        mesh.position.copy(pos);
        render();
      });
```

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const size = 5;
  const near = 5;
  const far = 50;
  const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-size, size, size, -size, near, far);
  camera.position.set(5, 7, 12);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('white');
  
  const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10);
  scene.add(gridHelper);

  const cubeSize = 1;
  const cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize);
  const cubeMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'red'});
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat);
  scene.add(mesh);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render() {
    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const aspect = renderer.domElement.clientWidth / renderer.domElement.clientHeight;
      camera.left  = -size * aspect;
      camera.right =  size * aspect;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  render();
  
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    // get a canvas content pixel position
    const {width, height} = renderer.domElement;
    const canvasX = (e.clientX - rect.left) * width / rect.width;
    const canvasY = (e.clientY - rect.top) * height / rect.height;
    
    const clipX = (canvasX / width)  *  2 - 1;
    const clipY = (canvasY / height) * -2 + 1;
        
    // get the object's clip space Z
    const clipPos = new THREE.Vector3();
    mesh.getWorldPosition(clipPos);
    clipPos.project(camera);

    // note this code moves the object in the plane
    // of the camera, not the plane of the grid
    const pos = new THREE.Vector3(clipX, clipY, clipPos.z);
    pos.unproject(camera);
    mesh.position.copy(pos);
    render();
  });
  
  window.addEventListener('resize', render);
}

main();
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r112/build/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

note the same code will also work for a `PerspecitveCamera`

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 60;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 50;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, 1, near, far);
  camera.position.set(2, 5, 10);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color('white');
  
  const gridHelper = new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10);
  scene.add(gridHelper);

  const cubeSize = 1;
  const cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(cubeSize, cubeSize, cubeSize);
  const cubeMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'red'});
  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeo, cubeMat);
  scene.add(mesh);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render() {
    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      camera.aspect = renderer.domElement.clientWidth / renderer.domElement.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  }
  render();
  
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    // get a canvas content pixel position
    const {width, height} = renderer.domElement;
    const canvasX = (e.clientX - rect.left) * width / rect.width;
    const canvasY = (e.clientY - rect.top) * height / rect.height;
    
    const clipX = (canvasX / width)  *  2 - 1;
    const clipY = (canvasY / height) * -2 + 1;
        
    // get the object's clip space Z
    const clipPos = new THREE.Vector3();
    mesh.getWorldPosition(clipPos);
    clipPos.project(camera);

    // note: this code moves the object in the plane
    // of the camera not the plane of the grid
    const pos = new THREE.Vector3(clipX, clipY, clipPos.z);
    pos.unproject(camera);
    mesh.position.copy(pos);
    render();
  });
  
  window.addEventListener('resize', render);
}

main();
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r112/build/three.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

If your canvas is css transformed then [see this](https://gist.github.com/greggman/c28bfbe50f6a27e53626a6860cf168a3)

note that if you wanted to move the object on the grid (or any arbitrary plane) than a trivial solution is to use the RayCaster against an invisible plane.

Also, if your object is has parents in the scene that are translated, rotated or scaled then just

```
    const parent = object.parent;
    scene.attach(object);

    // move the object as above

    parent.attach(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the function is not needed for an orthographic camera. We just need to translate the screen system coordinates to the three.js system coordinates. Following function can be used for that:

```
convertCoords(x, y, z) {
        return {
            x: x - this.width / 2,
            y: -1*y + this.height / 2,
            z
        }
}
```

Comment: Not really true. An orthographic camera can be positioned anywhere and pointed in any direction. This code will only work under very specific exceptions