# How to Grab or Drag Objects with React Three Rapier

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber, rapier, rapier-3d

> I've also asked [this question on Three.js Discourse](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-grab-or-drag-objects-with-react-three-rapier/59534).

I'm trying to add grabbing functionality to my scene, with physics as well.

So far, the closest I've got was [this CodeSandbox by gallant-sunset-6fjdgg](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/gallant-sunset-6fjdgg?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.jsx%3A17%2C26), coming from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69429351/4756173).

The problems/limitations with that sandbox are:

- It doesn't feature physics
- The object only moves around the xy axes.

Does anyone know how to add physics and a movement across the z axis to it? Maybe there's a way with `useFrame`?

Here's the code for reference:

`App.jsx`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import Obj from "./Obj.jsx";
import { OrthographicCamera, OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";
import * as THREE from "three";

export default function App() {
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
  const floorPlane = new THREE.Plane(new THREE.Vector3(0, 1, 0), 0);

  return (
    <Canvas style={{ background: "white" }} shadows dpr={[1, 2]}>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
      <directionalLight
        intensity={0.5}
        castShadow
        shadow-mapSize-height={1512}
        shadow-mapSize-width={1512}
      />

      <mesh
        rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}
        position={[0, -0.1, 0]}
        receiveShadow
      >
        <planeBufferGeometry attach="geometry" args={[30, 30]} receiveShadow />
        <meshPhongMaterial
          attach="material"
          color="#ccc"
          side={THREE.DoubleSide}
          receiveShadow
        />
      </mesh>

      <planeHelper args={[floorPlane, 5, "red"]} />

      <gridHelper args={[100, 100]} />

      <Obj setIsDragging={setIsDragging} floorPlane={floorPlane} />

      <OrthographicCamera makeDefault zoom={50} position={[0, 40, 200]} />

      <OrbitControls minZoom={10} maxZoom={50} enabled={!isDragging} />
    </Canvas>
  );
}
```

`Obj.jsx`

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { useDrag } from "@use-gesture/react";
import { animated, useSpring } from "@react-spring/three";
import { useThree } from "@react-three/fiber";
import * as THREE from "three";

function Obj({ setIsDragging, floorPlane }) {
  const [pos, setPos] = useState([0, 1, 0]);
  const { size, viewport } = useThree();
  const aspect = size.width / viewport.width;

  let planeIntersectPoint = new THREE.Vector3();

  const dragObjectRef = useRef();

  const [spring, api] = useSpring(() => ({
    // position: [0, 0, 0],
    position: pos,
    scale: 1,
    rotation: [0, 0, 0],
    config: { friction: 10 },
  }));

  const bind = useDrag(
    ({ active, movement: [x, y], timeStamp, event }) => {
      if (active) {
        event.ray.intersectPlane(floorPlane, planeIntersectPoint);
        setPos([planeIntersectPoint.x, 1.5, planeIntersectPoint.z]);
      }

      setIsDragging(active);

      api.start({
        // position: active ? [x / aspect, -y / aspect, 0] : [0, 0, 0],
        position: pos,
        scale: active ? 1.2 : 1,
        rotation: [y / aspect, x / aspect, 0],
      });
      return timeStamp;
    },
    { delay: true }
  );

  return (
    <animated.mesh {...spring} {...bind()} castShadow>
      <dodecahedronBufferGeometry
        ref={dragObjectRef}
        attach="geometry"
        args={[1.4, 0]}
      />
      <meshNormalMaterial attach="material" />
    </animated.mesh>
  );
}

export default Obj;
```